# Automatically preform a task after an event in JIRA.

Tags: workflow, jira

For our company we first move items to resolved while we are waiting for a release and then after the release we move all resolved tickets to Closed. Is there some kinda of automation that can be used to close these tickets after their fixVersion is released?

Comment: There is a Jira Command Line Interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write your own Event Listener that will subscribe to Issue Update event and will check if FixVersion was changed and will change issue's status to 'Closed'.

Here are some links that will get you started:

[Listeners](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Listeners)

[Plugin Tutorial - Writing JIRA event listeners with the atlassian-event library](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Plugin+Tutorial+-+Writing+JIRA+event+listeners+with+the+atlassian-event+library)

But before you start writing your plugin maybe you need to change your company procedure in regards to closing issues. Usually programmers resolve an issue and a person who created an issue closes it after testing. Here is a good discussion about close vs resolve - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4718505/941776. Is there a particular need to close issues when they are released?